# Filepond process all files in one request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, filepond

I am using react-filepond to process multiple files. I need to send all files together to the API in one request as opposed to multiple request per each file:

```
// Import the Image EXIF Orientation and Image Preview plugins
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation'
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview'
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css'

// Register the plugins
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview)

function App() {
  console.log('TEST');
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
  console.log(files);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FilePond
        server='/api'
        files={files}
        allowMultiple={true}
        onupdatefiles={setFiles}
        labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/KimGenius/React-file-pond).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `server` property. You can map your `files` array to file objects, `files.map(item => item.file)`, then you pass the file items to a `FormData` object and send the `formData` object to the server.

```
const formData = new FormData();
files.map(item => item.file).forEach(file => formData.append('my-file', file))

// send formData to server with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`
```

Comment: seems unnecessary to map it... `files.forEach(item => formData.append('my-file', item.file))`

Comment: @Endless the `files` array is an array of file items, not file objects. Therefor they need to mapped to actual file objects first.

Comment: Endless was right, re-read 2 years later :D no need to map.